# Getting value from database custom table not working in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, get

I have created a wordpress table with wp_compare_post with following column id, user_id, post_id, post_type. I have attached the image of the database.
[image]

**Below is the coading for viewing data from database**

```
function compare_counting(){
    global $wpdb;
    //get user id
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->compare_post WHERE user_id = '$user_ID '";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
            echo $result->post_id.',';
        }
    }
```

But getting following error.

```
Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$compare_post in
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be because you need to use $wpdb->prefix

Try this:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."compare_post WHERE user_id = '$user_ID'";`